how to omit COMMAND EXECUTION ERROR when test fails
I am running an AWS CodePipeline and running a pytest, according to the success or failure I will run the scripts. But my make test when failed exists with COMMAND EXECUTION ERROR . How can I stop the scripting from existing, rather use the result from the script in running other tasks.
MakeFile
test:
  python -m pytest tests.py

yaml file
make test --keep-going
echo $?
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  // task 1
else 
  // task 2
fi

I will be using the value of $? to decide which task to run.

This question is similar to: Bash get exit status of command when 'set -e' is active?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

(TL;DR if make test --keep-going; then echo 'Success'; else echo 'Fail'; fi)

Use "2>&1 > /dev/null" at the end of your script so all output is redirected to the Linux's null device.
Example: ./YourBashScriptHere.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null
If all you want is the output from $?, that's the most effective way to get rid of all output.

This issue addresses the problem of not displaying the error message in the console but does not solve the main question which is how to prevent the script from exiting on an internal command error.

if make test --keep-going; then echo 'Success'; else echo 'Fail'; fi  worked. Thanks @STerliakov
